# Is the term "BIOS" still prevalent when referring to UEFI?

Tags: history

First of all, I am not sure whether this belongs to programming SE or in here- because I am asking about the usage of terms in English language, I decided to ask on here.

I was chatting to my brother about IT related things. I mentioned changing BIOS settings, and he said I should stop calling it "BIOS" (Basic Input Output System), and start saying "UEFI" (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface), which has pretty much replaced BIOS by now. This left me wondering: is "BIOS" still more prevalent than "UEFI"? Are there perhaps differences between US/EU English usage?

It's pretty obvious just from a cursory glance at Google that loads of tutorials, how-to's and blogs still use the word "BIOS", often in conjunction with UEFI or EFI. I also tried Google Trends but I worry that the search term "bios" is a duplicate of "biographies" so I am not confident that the results are valid. Any pointers as to the common usage of BIOS/UEFI would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a retired computer nerd/EE (who is admittedly not super current on terminology), but I've never heard of "UEFI".  "EFI" a little bit, I think.  But pretty much anyone who has mucked with computers for a few years at least has a vague understanding of "BIOS" (if only to know to shudder when someone says "You'll have to reload your BIOS").

Comment: Even though this ostensibly could be relevant to ELU (the history of particular acronym uses in English), it's so steeped in technology culture itself that a culture specific SE site would probably get more knowledgable answers. The question really isn't about the acronym but the prevalence of the technology itself.

Comment: I think most reasonably computer-savvy people probably have an inkling that the BIOS is ‘that thing you can enter by holding down some key (combo) when you start the computer, and which comes before the OS and controls stuff like how various hardware is loaded’. Most people would call that a BIOS, I think, whether that is an actual BIOS or something else like UEFI or OF. I’m aware that there’s a difference (though not wherein the actual difference lies), and I would still just call it a BIOS for simplicity. I might even call it an UEFI BIOS to indicate both type and function.

Comment: @Mitch I don’t think the question is really about the technology. It’s more akin to how we still ‘dial’ someone’s number (even though there’s no longer a dial on our phones), etc., and whether ‘BIOS’ has become a similarly disassociated, genericised (for lack of a better term) word that is just to describe something, even if it isn’t actually that thing anymore. An authoritative ELU answer should be possible, though I daresay it won’t be an easy one to substantiate.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Understood. All very technical. Like asking how people understand what a 'ring' is in math (is multiplication always commutative in a generic ring or do you have to specify). Probably best answered by that particular  technical community rather than general English.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I have asked for the question to be moved, but I haven't received any response. I am not sure that I am able to move it myself.

Comment: It's already pretty good. It depends on the context. Sometimes it can be interchangeable, sometimes it's not. Personally I've rarely heard people talk about the new cool features of their UEFI in comparison to their previous BIOS. Some of the features of UEFI haven't really taken off (IMO) so that might be responsibly for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

Since **BIOS** is just an acronym for **B**asic **I**nput/**O**utput **S**ystem, and has been used for the last 44 years (since 1975 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS))

> The term BIOS (Basic Input/Output System) was created by Gary Kildall and first appeared in the CP/M operating system in 1975, describing the machine-specific part of CP/M loaded during boot time that interfaces directly with the hardware.

And since I know computers haven't been using CP/M exclusively for the last 44 years (it's [latest release was in 1983; 36 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M#Legacy)), the name BIOS has been applied to virtually every *new* **B**asic **I**nput/**O**utput **S**ystem since 1983 regardless of how new & different they are and what new features they have, I see no need to suddenly start calling the latest system anything different.

Just because the latest system is technically called a [Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), it still does the same basic job, and I'm still going to call it a **B**asic **I**nput/**O**utput **S**ystem, or **BIOS**.

---

As an example, just because a new Goldendoodle (Golden Retriever + Poodle) knows a lot of new tricks that an old Husky or mutt doesn't, I'm not going to stop calling them both dogs.